# Ошибка Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть картинка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У неё по краям оранжевая рамка, которую мне нужно обрезать. Но для начала я решил раскрасить эта рамку в красный с помощью рекурсии, чтобы видеть как работает программа.

Вот основной код:

```py
import sys
from PIL import Image
from color_class import Color

sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000489)

BORDER_COLOR = Color(255, 194, 61)


def color_diff(c1, c2):
    print('def color diff')
    color_d = c1 - c2
    print('pass 2')
    return sum([abs(i) for i in color_d])


def is_border_color(color):
    print('def is_border_color')
    if isinstance(color, tuple):
        color = Color(*color)

    print('pass')
    print(BORDER_COLOR)
    print(color)

    color_d = color_diff(BORDER_COLOR, color)  # Здесь происходит ошибка
    print('color_d = ', color_d)
    return color_d < 195


def draw_border(i, j, pixels, sz):
    # Проверяем не выходим ли мы за границы массива
    if i not in range(0, sz[1]) or j not in range(0, sz[0]):
        return

    print(i, j)

    if not is_border_color(pixels[j, i]):
        return

    print('debug1')

    pixels[j, i] = 255, 0, 0

    print('debug2')

    for pi in [-1, 0, 1]:
        for pj in [-1, 0, 1]:
            # Запускаем рекурсию из соседних клеток
            draw_border(j + pj, i + pi, pixels, sz)


def cut_image(im_name):
    im = Image.open(im_name)
    pixels = im.load()
    width, height = im.size

    print(width, height)  # 1018*1017

    for coord in range(200):  # Ищем начало рамки
        if is_border_color(pixels[coord, coord]):
            # При обнаружении рамки запускаем рекурсию, которая закрасит рамку в красный
            draw_border(coord, coord, pixels, (width, height))
            # Рекурсии. достаточно запустить один раз, поэтому сразу выходим из цикла
            break

    im.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cut_image('not_cutted.jpg')
```

Вот еще код класса цвета, который тоже используются в программе, но тут ничего интересного:

```py
from random import randrange as rd


class Color:
    def __init__(self, *args, color_range=(256, 256, 256)):
        if args:
            self.r, self.g, self.b = args
        else:
            if isinstance(color_range, Color):
                color_range = color_range.tuple()
            self.r, self.g, self.b = rd(0, color_range[0]), rd(0, color_range[1]), rd(0, color_range[2])

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Color({self.r}, {self.g}, {self.b})'

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Color):
            return Color(self.r + other.r, self.g + other.g, self.b + other.b)
        elif isinstance(other, tuple):
            return Color(self.r + other[0], self.g + other[1], self.b + other[2])
        return Color(self.r + other, self.g + other, self.b + other)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Color):
            return Color(self.r - other.r, self.g - other.g, self.b - other.b)
        elif isinstance(other, tuple):
            return Color(self.r - other[0], self.g - other[1], self.b - other[2])
        return Color(self.r - other, self.g - other, self.b - other)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Color(self.r * other, self.g * other, self.b * other)

    def __mod__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Color):
            return Color(self.r % other.r, self.g % other.g, self.b % other.b)
        elif isinstance(other, tuple):
            return Color(self.r % other[0], self.g % other[1], self.b % other[2])
        return Color(self.r % other, self.g % other, self.b % other)

    def __imod__(self, other):
        return self % other

    def __floordiv__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Color):
            return Color(self.r // other.r, self.g // other.g, self.b // other.b)
        elif isinstance(other, tuple):
            return Color(self.r // other[0], self.g // other[1], self.b // other[2])
        return Color(self.r // other, self.g // other, self.b // other)

    def __ifloordiv__(self, other):
        return self // other

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        return self + other

    def __isub__(self, other):
        return self - other

    def __imul__(self, other):
        return self * other

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Color):
            return self.r < other.r and self.g < other.g and self.b < other.b
        elif isinstance(other, tuple):
            return self.r < other[0] and self.g < other[1] and self.b < other[2]
        return self.r < other and self.g < other and self.b < other

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter([self.r, self.g, self.b])

    def tuple(self):
        return self.r, self.g, self.b
```

В результате работы программы вылазит ошибка:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

Судя по выводу программы ошибка происходит в этой строчке

```
color_d = color_diff(BORDER_COLOR, color)
```

Причем в функцию color_diff программа не заходит. Вот я и не понимаю, где здесь, а главное почему ошибка происходит?!

Кто-нибудь может помочь?

Comment: А в чем чуть задачи? Кст, 0xC00000FD это ошибка переполнения стека. Сложно поверить, что рекурсия тут нужна, скорее всего это возможно переписать на циклы.

Comment: @gil9red Странно что стек переполняются. Я же установил достаточно большое ограничение  по рекурсии. На счет циклов да, можно переписать, но мне все-же хочется разобраться в этой проблеме

Comment: Скорее всего просто достигнут максимум стека вследствии слишком большой глубины рекурсии

Comment: Может красный подпадает под `is_border_color`, и оно заливает бесконечно поверх

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov к сожалению проблемы не в этом( Но спасибо что нашли баг в программе. А поиск проблемы я сегодня сильно сузил https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1164918/%d0%a3-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python3